# MainLooper vs runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am new to the world of Android. What is exactly the difference between following and which one I should use to run a method on main thread ?

1)

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do some thing
    }
};
mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
```

2)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do some thing
    }
});
```

Comment: if you look at the source code for Activity, you'll see that `runOnUiThread` does pretty much the same thing, except it runs directly if you call it already on the ui thread. I would use the second one, as there is no need to create another handler

Comment: @njzk2 Why don't you post that as an answer? Perhaps with a snippet of that source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the source code for Activity:

```
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

You can see that `runOnUiThread` does pretty much the same thing, which is posting a `Runnable` on a `Handler`. The main difference is that it runs directly if you call it already while being already on the ui thread.

I would use the second one, as there is no need to create another handler when you can use the one of the `Activity`.

The first case is to be used when you don't have an `Activity` or a `View` at hand on which you can post your `Runnable` (Such as in `Service`s).

Also, you'll notice that the default constructor of `Handler` uses the `Looper` of the current Thread, meaning you don't have to get the mainLooper if you are creating the `Handler` from the UI thread.

Answer (score 3):

Between the two code samples that you posted, there's no real difference and you can use the shorter notation. There is, however, a related construction where there *is* a big difference:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Handler.Callback {

     // constructors and onCreate and stuff

    private static final int FOO = 1;
    private static final int BAR = 2;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), this);

    private void sendFooMessage(int arg1, String arg2) {
        mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(FOO, arg1, 0, arg2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
        case FOO:
             //handle the foo event
             return true;
        case BAR:
             //handle the bar action
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The thing that's so special about this construct is that you're **not creating any garbage** (*). There is no single-shot `Runnable` instance that goes onto the garbage collector. The `Handler.obtainMessage(...)` methods take the `Message` objects from a pool where they are reused again and again.

If you're firing messages during cases where keeping the 60fps is important, this no-garbage construction helps keep everything going smooth by preventing garbage collector pauses.

*) not by the messages themselves anyway, you still need to take care with the args and stuff.